# Is there a way to cast Func<v1,v2,out1> to Func<out1> given I know v1 and v2?

Tags: c#, events, lambda, casting, delegates

So I have this function that takes a function with no parameters:

```
public static bool RetryUntilSuccessOrTimeout(Func<bool> task, TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        bool success = false;
        int elapsed = 0;
        while ((!success) && (elapsed < timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            elapsed += 1000;
            success = task();
        }
        return success;
    }
```

And then I have a bunch of functions like:

```
private static bool OnDeleted(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e){...}
private static bool OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e){...}
private static bool OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e){...}
```

I have a function that takes same aruments as those three. So I have that information provided. Is there a way to pass these function as ones not taking any arguments (because I provide them) so i can pass it into the "task" of RetryUntilSuccessOrTimeout() ?

An encapsulating image of the problem:

[OnDirEvent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cnwi.png)

Comment: Iam innerly cringing when I see any func called like this. In your situation its ok, when the func is null you probably want to raise an exception. I habitly call these by `task?.Invoke() ?? true` when a plausible default is at hand. Otherwise handle null ref in place / upstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Basically you just do

```
() => func(a, b)
```

Comment: What you want is called "partial function application". C# doesn't have language-level support for it like some languages (F#, Haskell), but using lambda expressions works in some cases.

Comment: @stt106 No, it's not.  It's partial function application, as was mentioned in the previous comment.  Currying that function would be taking a `Func<object, FileSystemEventArgs, bool>` and  creating a `Func<Object, Func<FileSystemEventArgs, bool>>`.